# tatelerik for asp net mvc requires nuget package manager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I downloaded telerik and installed it , i got the visual studio 2013 already installed on my PC . now when i click on new project -> c# -> web -> "telerik ASP.NET MVC Application" opotion"talerik for asp net mvc requires nuget package manager"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed the following NuGet package Manager for visual studio 2013 - which solved my problem -hopefully someone will find it helpfull .

Note : for visual studio 2010,2012 there are links available in the related page

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ec1526c-4a8c-4a84-b702-b21a8f5293ca